# RHEL 6.6 pip after python upgrade "ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode"

Tags: python, rhel6, upgrade, pip

I originally have python 2.6 and installed 2.7 and want to use pip to install some libraries like futures (with an s :)). Unfortunately, it seems like pip's libraries has been messed up. When type pip on the command line it produces this error:

```
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/array.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_FromUnicode
```

Comment: You are probably going to have to reinstall the whole system. Python is a critical component and should not be upgraded in place.

Comment: I am sorry I mean I kept 2.6 and installed 2.7; I did not remove 2.6 or uninstalled it at all. I edited this part of the question. Does it make sense now?